# How to parse JSON data into HTML elemnets

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have a JSON data with HTML.

Like this:

```
"elements":[
{
   "element":".dyno-text",
   "value":"This fun here.<br> <button type='button' onclick='changeTheme(this)' data-theme='sketchy' class='theme-link btn btn-light'>Sketchy</button>",
   "class": 'text-success'
}
]
```

How will I parse this JSON data to Bootstrap Layout Design for example: Button will come to real.

Thanks

Comment: what is the expected output rendered? ls it `<dyno-text class="text-success">This fun here.<br> <button type='button' onclick='changeTheme(this)' data-theme='sketchy' class='theme-link btn btn-light'>Sketchy</button></dyno-text>`?

Comment: It should output the value in a div like: `<div>This fun here. <button class="theme-link btn btn-light">Sketchy</button></div>`

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Comment: if `elements.value` has multiple `<button>`, what is the output? two buttons with same classes?

Comment: Every button has it's own classes.

Comment: Already answer for n value.

Answer (score 1):

Uses `Vue.component` to assembly JSON as one component may be one solution.

But you may need to adjust the HTML template in JSON. Because for supporting some features such as `onclick`, binding `class`, it will be one serious headache.

Below is one demo which may provide you some ideas how to reach your goal.

```js
new Vue ({
  el:'#app',
  data () {
    return {
      "elements":[
        {
           "element":"dyno-text",
           "value":"This fun here.<br> <button type='button' @click='changeTheme(this)' data-theme='sketchy' class='theme-link btn btn-light'>Sketchy</button>",
           "class": 'text-success',
           "methods": {
             // changed onclick to @click, if you still like to use 'onclick' in the template, you have to define window.changeTheme
             changeTheme: function(obj) {console.log('clicked')}
           }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createComponent(element) {
      /*window.changeTheme = function () {
        console.log('clicked by onclick')
      }*/
      return Vue.component(element.element, {
        template: `<div ref="test">${element.value}</div>`,
        mounted: function () {
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.$refs.test.querySelector('button.btn').classList.add(element.class)
            // or adjust your template in JSON like `<button :class="classes"/>`, then binds element.class to data property=classes
          })
        },
        methods: element.methods
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <div v-for="(item, index) in elements" :key="index">
          <component :is="createComponent(item)"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this; I changed the element in order to create a known htmlElement, so what you do here is to iterate your array of elements and you insert them inside the body, set the value, and toggle the class.

--Edit--

Cleanner solution thanks to pointing it out supercool

[Documentation of classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
    let elements=[
    {
       "element":"div",
       "value":"This fun here.<br> <button type='button' onclick='changeTheme(this)' data-theme='sketchy' class='theme-link btn btn-light'>Sketchy</button>",
       "class": 'text-success'
    }
    ]

    elements.forEach((elemen,i)=>{
    
    let createdElement= document.createElement(elemen.element)
    createdElement.innerHTML = elemen.value
    createdElement.classList.toggle(elemen.class)
    document.body.appendChild(createdElement)

      })
```

Comment: You should do appendChild at last and you can neglect document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Nice catch I changed it. Thanks!